# Twitter Search api - Tweets containing url are not returned in search result

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter rest api for reading user's twitter feed and searching tweets for specific hashtags. But twitter search api do not return tweets containing url in search result.

E.g. I have 2 tweets a) #hashtag b) #hashtag http://google.co.in/

below api returns only first tweet in search result
[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23promojuice](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23hashtag)
Tweets containing any url are not returned in search result.

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
You need to provide more info on context/background and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Twitter search API has a limit of 7 days. Check the API documentation

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets
>   published in the past 7 days.

The key word is **sampling**, Twitter Search API only returned what they consider relevant tweets.